# How to group deployments under common template name in OpenShift console

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I am trying to unclutter my openshift "Overview" web console. Each deployment is showing up inside a collapsible box that is titled with the name of the template where the deployment was declared. The problem is that I have many deployments defined inside a single template, so when the service deployment boxes are all collapsed, It is difficult to tell what is in each since they all have the same title. I have to look to the right at the service URL to see which one it is.

Here is a partial template YAML showing only relevant info:

```
kind: Template
metadata:
  name: my-web-app
...
objects:
- kind: DeploymentConfig
  metadata:
    name: "foo-service"
...
- kind: DeploymentConfig
  metadata:
    name: "bar-service"
```

When deployed, I see on the Openshift overview console two separate boxes, both labeled "my-web-app". I have to open the box to see the service name (or read the URL on the right). I can *manually* link the two services via the console's GUI so that they appear under the same template name the way I want, but I would like this to happen automagically. Is there a template parameter I can set to either link the associated services, or at least rename the box that the service is specified in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that OpenShift has fixed this issue with release 1.4. I was using 1.3.1. I see now that the console (overview) displays the service name on the top bar.

I did not need to try the solution offered by Graham Dumpleton, though it may still be useful for grouping like services.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a specific annotation. See:

- https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/templates.html#other-recommendations